# Exact timing of the display of images and user reactions in Flutter applications

Tags: dart, flutter

I have to create an app for psychological reaction time testing. For that purpose I have to control exactly when an image is 
visible and exactly measure the delay between the onset of the visibility of the image and the onset of the reaction (e.g. tap event). 
How can I achieve that in Flutter? Specifically, what is the most efficient way to show and hide several different images in the same place and  how can I exactly know the onset of the tap event in relation to the onset of the real and full visibility to the user taking into consideration the frame rate of the device? Is there way to get low-level control over that process. Flutter seems to expose a high-level api, usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made an attempt that is possibly exactly what you are looking for, my logic is as follows:

1. Add a listener to the image being presented.
2. Using `Stopwatch` class, I notify my object to start counting time once the image is displayed.
3. When clicking on the correct answer, I stop my `Stopwatch` to stop counting.
4. Save my current score, and carry on to the next question.

**Note:**

- In this example, for the sake of simplicity, I did not make an account for which answer is correct and which is not.
- I create a new `StatelessWidget` to hold each question, using `PageView.builder` might be a good use here as well.

**Simple Example:**

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int score = 0;

class TimeTest extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget nextQuestionWidget; //to navigate
  String question;
  NetworkImage questionImage;
  List<String> answers;

  TimeTest(
      {this.questionImage, this.question, this.answers, this.nextQuestionWidget });

  @override
  _TimeTestState createState() => new _TimeTestState();
}

class _TimeTestState extends State<TimeTest> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool _loading = true;
  Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.questionImage.resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener((_, __) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _loading = false;
        });
        timer.start();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Time Test"),),
      body: new Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(widget.question),
            new Divider(height: 15.0, color: Colors.blueAccent,),
            new CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: widget.questionImage,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,),
            new Container(height: 15.0,),
            new Column(
              children: new List.generate(widget.answers.length, (int index) {
                return new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ///TODO
                    ///add conditions for correct or incorrect answers
                    ///and some manipulation on the score
                    timer.stop();
                    score = score + timer.elapsedMilliseconds;
                    print(score);
                    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                        content: new Text(
                            "Your answered this question in ${timer
                                .elapsedMilliseconds}ms")));

                    ///Hold on before moving to the next question
                    new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => widget.nextQuestionWidget));
                    });
                  }, child: new Text(widget.answers[index]),);
              }),
            )
          ],

        ),),
    );
  }
}


class QuestionOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TimeTest(question: "Which animal is in this photo?",
      questionImage: new NetworkImage(
          "http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Tiger-free-to-use-clipart.png"),
      answers: ["Lion", "Tiger", "Cheetah"],
      nextQuestionWidget: new QuestionTwo(),);
  }
}

class QuestionTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TimeTest(question: "Which bird is in this photo?",
      questionImage: new NetworkImage(
          "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/q/7/9/j/q/eagle-hi.png"),
      answers: ["Hawk", "Eagle", "Falcon"],
      nextQuestionWidget: new ResultPage(),);
  }
}

class ResultPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Result"),),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text("CONGRATULATIONS! Your score is $score milliseconds"),),
    );
  }
}
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new QuestionOne()));
}
```

Comment: This solution pushes a new Route on the screen. Isn't it like a memory leak with large numbers of Routes. I would rather replace the existing image How can I achive that?

Comment: I do not want to use pushReplacement, because it replaces an entire widget. Is it istead possible to simply and only exchange the image and be notified exactly when it is displayed?

Comment: Yes, that is why I mentioned PageView.builder

Comment: But wait, do not you want to change the question and the answers as well ?? Why are you only talking about the image exchange ?

Comment: There is another way also that might be even better which storing all your question data in an object for each and change the state to view the next object/question in a list when an answer is chosen.